# PyMCのsample関数でlist index out of rangeエラーが発生した時の修正方法について

Tags: python, python3

現在、ベイズ推論とMCMCのフリーソフトという書籍のPyMCのチュートリアル的な章を学んでいるのですが、
以下のコードの`ts=[pm.sample(itenum, step, chains=i,progressbar=False) for i in range(chainnum)]`という部分で、`IndexError: list index out of range`というエラーが出てしまいます。
このエラーを回避して正常に動作させるのは、該当箇所をどのように修正すれば良いでしょうか。

環境は、google colabで、python3.6です。

```
import pymc3 as pm
import time
from pymc3.backends.base import merge_traces
import numpy as np

N=40
X=np.random.uniform(10,size=N)
Y=X*30+4+np.random.normal(0,16,size=N)

multicore=False
saveimage=False

itenum=1000
t0=time.clock()
chainnum=3

with pm.Model() as model:
  alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=20)
  beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=20)
  sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0)
  y = pm.Normal('y', mu=beta*X + alpha, sd=sigma, observed=Y)
  start = pm.find_MAP()
  step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)

with model:
  if(multicore):
    trace = pm.sample(itenum, step, start=start, njobs=chainnum, random_seed=range(chainnum), progress_bar=False)
  else:
    ts=[pm.sample(itenum, step, chains=i,progressbar=False) for i in range(chainnum)]
    trace=merge_traces(ts)
  if(saveimage):
    pm.traceplot(trace).savefig("simple_linear_trace.png")
  print("Rhat="+str(pm.gelman_rubin(trace)))

t1=time.clock()
print("elapsed time="+str(t1-t0))
```

具体的なエラー内容は以下です。

```
<ipython-input-8-b9c1eab04925> in <listcomp>(.0)
     22     trace = pm.sample(itenum, step, start=start, njobs=chainnum, random_seed=list(range(chainnum)), progress_bar=False)
     23   else:
---> 24     ts=[pm.sample(itenum, step, chains=i,progressbar=False) for i in list(range(chainnum))]
     25     trace=merge_traces(ts)
     26   if(saveimage):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymc3/sampling.py in sample(draws, step, init, n_init, start, trace, chain_idx, chains, cores, tune, progressbar, model, random_seed, discard_tuned_samples, compute_convergence_checks, **kwargs)
    458 
    459         discard = tune if discard_tuned_samples else 0
--> 460         trace = trace[discard:]
    461 
    462         if compute_convergence_checks:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymc3/backends/base.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    290     def __getitem__(self, idx):
    291         if isinstance(idx, slice):
--> 292             return self._slice(idx)
    293 
    294         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymc3/backends/base.py in _slice(self, slice)
    496         new_traces = [trace._slice(slice) for trace in self._straces.values()]
    497         trace = MultiTrace(new_traces)
--> 498         idxs = slice.indices(len(self))
    499         trace._report = self._report._slice(*idxs)
    500         return trace

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymc3/backends/base.py in __len__(self)
    341 
    342     def __len__(self):
--> 343         chain = self.chains[-1]
    344         return len(self._straces[chain])
    345 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そのエラーそのものは`chains=i`の`i`が`0`だから発生するようです。その行の後ろの`range(chainnum)`を`range(1, chainnum)`に変更すると処理は行われるようですが、処理が継続した先で結局別のエラーが発生してダンマリ状態になります。このPython2系のソース [vol1/watanabe/code1.py](https://github.com/iwanami-datascience/vol1/blob/master/watanabe/code1.py) を移植しようとしているのでしょうが、5年以上前の古い物なので環境が色々変わって難しいのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法で該当のエラーは回避できましたが、処理の途中で別のエラーが発生しました。おっしゃられる通り、古い資料で難しため、ここまでにしようと思います。